# How to use internet in raspberry pi when it is directly connected to my laptop via Ethernet cable?

Tags: ssh, internet

I have connected my Raspberry pi DIRECTLY to my laptop using Ethernet cable. I use SSH client Putty and X-11 forwarding to access terminal and desktop of pi. This is because i do not have separate keyboard, mouse and display for my pi. Also i do not have WI-FI dongle to my pi. i use beetel dongle for internet on my windows 7 laptop. i need to use internet in my pi. so can some one give me solution to access internet on pi while i connect it directly to my laptop.

PS: 1) i do not have extra key board and display for my pi
    2) i do not have wifi dongle for pi
    3) i use 3g beetel dongle for internet on my win 7 laptop.

Comment: I've been struggling with this long time ago and haven't found a solution.  Maybe it will be easier to attach the 3G dongle to your Pi and setup your laptop to use the internet via the Pi.  I'm sure there's info to be found on how to do that and if not, chances are higher to find people who can help you with getting there.

Comment: yes i have thought about that and found a way in the link https://www.crazypi.com/index.php?route=blog/post&post_id=20.  But luk at the first step to install usb mode switch. it requires internet connection to pi which i dont have!

Comment: @Anantha yes you're right.  Typical chicken and egg situation.  Perhaps a 3G router like the [TP-Link TL-MR3420](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4691_TL-MR3420.html) could help you - over here in Asia they're about $30 a pop.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is bridge the network adaptors in your W7 machine.
[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7) is a guide to do so.

This will  allow you to forward the internet traffic from your Wan card to your Ethernet port.

Comment: i tried. there is no option to bridge LAN with dongle iam using. :/

Comment: Maybe the vendor of the dongle disallows this In any case case;
You could try working the other way round, connect your Pi with the 3G dongle, and bridge the network to your windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time by using ICS (Internet Connection Sharing).  [Here is a link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7) that describes how to set this up, it's very easy.